# Writing an UnHash Method Based on The Following Hash Method

Tags: c#, .net, hash

Some time ago I went through an interview process and got stumped on a technical question.
The problem to solve was given the hash method below, write a corresponding unhash method.

```
    static Int64 hashThis (String s)
    {
        Int64 h = 7;
        String letters = "acdegiklmnoprsuw";

        for (Int32 i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
        {
            h = (h * 37 + letters.IndexOf(s[i]));
        }

        return h;
    }
```

My failed progress thus far is this:

```
static String unhashThis(Int64 integer)
    {
        Int64 h = 7;
        String letters = "acdegiklmnoprsuw";
        String unhashed = "";

        // as long as h < than integer passed in
        // this is so we iterate the correct number of times
        for (Int32 i = 0; h < integer; i++)
        {
            h = (h * 37 + letters.IndexOf(letters[i]));
            Int64 rem = h % 7;
            Int64 rem2 = 7 % h;
            //unhashed += letters[(int)h];
            //if (h > letters.Length)
            //{
            //    // loop through the letters to find the character
            //    for (int j = 0; j < h; j++)
            //    {
            //        if (j == letters.Length)
            //        {
            //            j = 0;
            //        }
            //        else
            //        {
            //            unhashed += letters[j];
            //        }
            //    }
            //}
        }

        return unhashed;
```

Just to reiterate I am revisiting this as I am trying to get better at problem solving so that I can do better on future interviews.

Comment: Are hash functions reversible?

Comment: @cassandrad I assume that this particular one is, due to it being asked of me. But I guess it depends on the approach.

Comment: `letters` doesn't have several letters like “b” and “f”. If input string will consist only of these letters, it will have the same hash. How unhash function should handle such collisions?

Comment: @cassandrad the example provided to me was that the string hashed was "igloocool". It only consists of the letters within the string variable.

Comment: IMHO, it's not truly a hash function since it doesn't map the input value to an output value from a *fixed-sized* output value domain: at some point, even Int64 will overflow. Though this could easily be fixed with some added modulo operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this works:

```
static String unHashThis(Int64 hash)
{
    String letters = "acdegiklmnoprsuw";
    String phrase = "";
    while (hash >= 7 * 37)
    {
        int i = (int)(hash % 37);
        phrase = letters[i]+phrase;
        hash = (hash - hash % 37) / 37;
    }

    return phrase;
}
```

Notes:

First if the string you use to hash and unhash this it's has characters that are not in the "letters" string, it's going to fail

Try to figure why it works, if you can't, tell me and I'll explain

This is closer to encrypton than to Hashing I believe, Hash is not meant to UN-Hash

Comment: Thanks for your very helpful solution!
Really appreciate you taking the time.

I understand why it works, but I was wondering how you came to that solution using the modulo. I am trying to improve my problem solving skills and was hoping to gain some insight.

Thanks again!

Comment: When trying to "undo" things it's a really good approach to try to see stuff backwards, So if I want to get all the letters, probably a good a idea is to start with the last one it added (it added to the hash, so to speak).
I know he multiplies by 37 before adding a letter so I know the combination of letters before the last one is added  is a multiple of 37, but not the last letter value, so I extract, divide and repeat

PS: When adding to something that is multiplying, module is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Nice question. Here is a Python version that also handles characters missing in `letters`. It uses the fact that `find` returns *-1* when the string is not found (like `IndexOf` in C#):

```py
C = 37  # must be > len(letters)
letters = "cdategiorkswlm"


def hash_this(s):
    h = 7
    for ch in s:
        h = h * C + letters.find(ch)
    return h;


def unhash_this(v):
    h = 7
    s = ''
    while v > h:
        j = int(v % C)
        if j >= len(letters):
            j = -1
        v = (v - j) // C
        s += '_' if j == -1 else letters[j]
    return s[::-1]
```

```py
hash_this('stackoverflow')
# 402116075536062288302

unhash_this(hash_this('stackoverflow'))
# 'stacko_er_low'
```